# How can I get the raw message in the errorHandler?

Tags: spring-kafka

In a Spring Boot service consuming from kafka using the spring-kafka dependency.

I have created my own error handler implementing the CommonErrorHandler.
Now when I get a message, Id like to somehow get the original message before it was deserialized.

Is this possible?